# Can an unpolarised (C7) plug be used safely in place of a polarised (C7P) plug?

Tags: power, iec

I bought this AC adapter from the US to replace a broken Australian one. Unfortunately, the power brick is keyed for use with the polarised C7P plug. Unpolarised C7 appears to be the standard in Australia as I cannot find any polarised C7 plugs with Au sockets. And the AC adapter has the Class 2 symbol (double square). My question is whether I can plug a standard unpolarised "figure 8" style plug into the polarised adapter since they physically fit? Will "C" work with "A", or is only "B+A" safe? Do I have to orient the male plug a certain way?[image][image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Most probably yes. Is it double isolated (double square symbol)?

Comment: The AC adapter does have the double square symbol (Class 2). Thank you!

Comment: I can only guess it's down to some local legislation or regulation. Any normal double insulated won't care about input polarity.

Comment: Ok great thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The keying is designed to prevent dangerous combinations, so if it fits it should be fine.

Comment: I've read that appliances themselves do not care about input polarity. But safety wise polarity matters only if the appliance is not double insulated. That is, as long as an appliance is double insulated, input polarity should not matter, in terms of safety either. Is this true?

Comment: Non-double insulated mains devices normally need to have an earth connection, so the relevance to these non-earthed connectors is limited.  More than that, over the years I've seen two instances of sockets with L-N reversal, so I would not want to rely on that anyway.